# How do you finish a stalemating game?

Tags: league-of-legends

I just lost my second game where the teams were fairly even, all the enemy turrets were down, but we lose a team fight and just get rolled while we're waiting ~70 seconds to respawn.

When we kill all the inhibitors in a raid, we'll keep them bottled up in their base for minutes while they run around killing minions, but farming hardly matters at this stage when we're capped out on equipment and blowing money on pots.  Baron and dragon are killed every time they're up, but the buff seems slight at best at this point.  Our team composition was probably worse at this extreme late-game, where they had 2 good ranged AD/AP carries that could easily focus one of us down at a time, but is there any way around this?

If one or two of us died despite all lanes pushed to their base with super-minions, they would smartly dive while leaving one of them at base to manage minions.  We tried just sitting in a bush in their jungle waiting for them to split up, but any time we were all up they barely went 2 feet outside of their base.

How can you win games like this where your extreme-late-game composition is worse than the enemy team and their carries turn semi-tanky?

Comment: Could you tell us both team's composition?

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, there's no sure-fire way of resolving this situation.

You won't be able to rely on minions to take out their towers and nexus, especially if their uber status gets to the point where they can start defending their respawning inhibitors. If you get really lucky and get their nexus towers down, you could just farm minions hard enough for yours to take the nexus down a bit then try to dive the nexus. I'd consider this a [Hail Mary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_Mary_pass#In_other_fields) more than anything else, though.

**If you know you're going up against a team that is going to steamroll you once they get maxxed out (2+ carries), the main goal is to take advantage of the fact that they will be weaker in the early game.** If you [zone](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0LCVsrpurI) the carries and/or kill them enough to keep them from getting geared and leveled, your team will get powerful enough to take their nexus before they can do anything about it.

**Assuming you find yourself in that unfortunate position anyway and forcing their team to split up isn't working, you absolutely have to focus the primary damage dealers down first.** If they stick together and you're not killing their carries first, you'll take way more damage than you will deal out over the course of the fight and you're sure to lose.

Comment: So we essentially we lost much earlier and our only hope was that they would make a serious error?

Comment: @NickT: In short: yes. At the point their carries were more out-geared than yours, the likelihood of pulling out a win was drastically lower than before. Luck on your part or misfortune (not Miss Fortune) on theirs would be the main way to swing it back. If you go up against a team with more carries than you, you have to take advantage of their slow start to stomp them or your end-game will be more of a nightmare than your average game. As you saw, even the Baron buff wasn't gaining you ground and you were fully-geared. That's serious business.

Answer (score 5):

Once you have reached this point, the team with the better comp is usually going to come out victorious, but like you said the trick is to try to just catch one of them off gaurd and kill them then just push, at 3v2 no matter what their team builup is they will lose at this point in the game. The trick to sway the game for you though is to play very conservativley and ensure noone on YOUR team gets killed, and also don't hesitate to change up your build. Just because A build works 90% of the time, maybe you are in a situation where a build change will be whats puts you over them. You will have a ton of gold by this point and will be able to buy pretty much anything you could need. For example if you usually play a tank and build a nice well balanced build and you are up against two heavy hitting ranged AD's then just sell any MR you have and put it all into armor. LoL is dynamic and should be played as such. Never tie yourself to a build, you should always be trying to counter the enemy. No team comp is unbeatable. Prioritize enenmies, change your build and outsmart them.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing you can do at this point, is change the fight to give yourself an advantage. If they wont leave their base you must split your group and attack from 2 directions, top and mid, or bot and mid. You need to force them to split up and make a mistake.

Ensure your items both offensive and defensive are appropriate, Either team loosing 1-2 players for 70 seconds can end the game very quickly. Emerica is exactly right with changing up your build. I have seen crazy things once games approach the 50 minute mark.

If you can get them to chase or push there is always the chance at a backdoor.

Guardian Angel and Hourglass can win you a team fight if the enemy isnt paying attention dumping all their dmg into a single player who popped invulnerability.

Make sure if you have the right items you load up on elixirs, get baron , and blue or red to those who will make the most use of it.

The game turns into chess at this point where you just need to tip the odds in your favor slightly and get a tiny advantage to exploit. Once you have the advantage all out push.

Answer (score 2):

> How can you win games like this where your extreme-late-game
>   composition is worse than the enemy team and their carries turn
>   semi-tanky?

I'm curious why you think your team comp was worse.  Did you lack ranged ad?  One way to counter this is to pick a better team (I know that's not always an option in blind pick).

You need to have a way to initiate fights (Ashe's arrow, Ahri's charm, Rammus's taunt, Singed, etc).  Ideally, it's something that will separate 1 enemy from the rest of his team, though a good team will dive in to protect the cc'd member.

You should start tailoring your items to exploit weaknesses.  Their carries can't have health, armor, mr, AND insane damage.  Is there a particular hero who's well fed?  Buy defense vs their primary damage type.

If you destroyed all the 3 inhibitors, each lane should be spawning 2 super minions; USE THEM!  Even late game, super minions cannot be ignored.  Actively harass the enemy champions when they try to kill them.

Finally, support your ranged ad.  This hero is designed to do physical damage and lots of it, making them best suited to destroy buildings.  It shouldn't take a maxed carry more than a few seconds to take an inhibitor from full heath to nothing; make that window happen for them!

tl;dir: If you've pushed them to their nexus and destroyed all 3 inhibitors, your ad carry should be able to harass them from behind super minions as the rest of the team protects him/her.

Answer (score 1):

With all inhibitors down, push the nexus. It can't stand up long against a full team of champions plus minions - if you have the slightest chance of killing it by focusing it, do so. It doesn't matter if they ace you if their nexus breaks.

ETA: I've unconsciously assumed that you killed the nexus turrets already. The towers are durable enough that it's not a good idea to try to sacrifice an ace in hopes of ending the game.

Answer (score 1):

split pushing helps but on different sides (not mid and bot / mid and top ) and try luring them out of the base.

try poking them and as soon as one of them goes to heal, unleash hell on the remaining ones.